# import pandas_datareader gives ImportError: cannot import name 'is_list_like'

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

I am working in a virtual environment. I am able to import and work in pandas without any error but when I am trying to `import pandas_datareader`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt
from matplotlib import style
import pandas_datareader as web
```

it is giving following error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stock.py", line 6, in <module>
    import pandas_datareader as web
  File "/home/xxxxx/django-apps/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas_datareader/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .data import (DataReader, Options, get_components_yahoo,
  File "/home/xxxxx/django-apps/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas_datareader/data.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pandas_datareader.fred import FredReader
  File "/home/xxxxx/django-apps/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas_datareader/fred.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.core.common import is_list_like
ImportError: cannot import name 'is_list_like'
(env) xxxxx@xxxxx-yyyyy ~/pyt $ python stock.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stock.py", line 6, in <module>
    import pandas_datareader
  File "/home/xxxxx/django-apps/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas_datareader/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .data import (DataReader, Options, get_components_yahoo,
  File "/home/xxxxx/django-apps/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas_datareader/data.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pandas_datareader.fred import FredReader
  File "/home/xxxxx/django-apps/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas_datareader/fred.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.core.common import is_list_like
ImportError: cannot import name 'is_list_like'
```

Comment: what is your pandas version?

Comment: pandas version is 0.23.0

Comment: It looks like your version of pandas_datareader is not compatible with brand new Pandas 0.23

Comment: Quite possible. Let me purge it and install an older version. Then I will check again thanks.

Comment: @MaxU working well with 0.21.0. Thanks

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I meet this error and I found a method to solve it. My pandas and pandas_datareader versions are 0.23 and 0.6.

```
Python 3.6.5 (default, Apr  1 2018, 05:46:30)
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas_datareader
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas_datareader/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .data import (DataReader, Options, get_components_yahoo,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas_datareader/data.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pandas_datareader.fred import FredReader
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas_datareader/fred.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.core.common import is_list_like
ImportError: cannot import name 'is_list_like'
```

[image]

Because the `is_list_like` is moved to pandas.api.types, I change the fred.py file which is highlighted in the picture. I replace `from pandas.core.common import is_list_like` with `from pandas.api.types import is_list_like`, and it works.

[image]

Comment: You can put ``pd.core.common.is_list_like = pd.api.types.is_list_like`` before you import ``pandas_datareader`` so you don't need to edit ``fred.py``.

Comment: I installed an earlier version of Pandas and it is working fine. So if someone wants to use pandas 0.23 then this seems to be correct method.

Comment: This work for as well, all I did was open the file and change the line 1 to this: `from pandas.api.types import is_list_like` the thing that I don't understand is that it seems that this was patch a while ago, and the latest library has this, which is what I have, does not include this patch.  anyway, thanks for tip.

Comment: @ramiro in which file did you place that line?

Comment: @DataGirl I put it in my python script just before I write ``import pandas_datareader``.

Comment: Modifying a library source is definitely a workaround that should be avoided. If you modify the highlighted path, you'll break `pandas` for the system-wide python3.6... something you really want to avoid. Ps. downgrading pandas to 0.23.0 with pandas_reader 0.6 didn't work for me.

Answer (score 98):

A solution **without** changing any files locally and **bypass** the version control of your package manager (pip) is to define *is_list_like* like this:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.core.common.is_list_like = pd.api.types.is_list_like
```

right before

```
import pandas_datareader as web
```

Furthermore this problem will be fixed in pandas_datareader version 0.7.0 release.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because it doesn't need to change any files to work.

Comment: agreed, 1 line of code fixes the problem until datareader 0.7 is ready

Answer (score 11):

This is due to the fact that `is_list_like` has been moved from `pandas.core.common` to `pandas.api.types` in Pandas 0.23.0. This issue has been repaired [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/pull/520) and will be a part of the Pandas Datareader 0.7.0 release. For now, I would recommend using the dev version of Datareader. Instructions for installing can be found in the [documentation](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#install-latest-development-version).

Answer (score 4):

If you are not working with pandas_datareader. you need to check your conda environment data reader is installed or not if not install than you can import this way this.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.core.common.is_list_like = pd.api.types.is_list_like
import pandas_datareader as web
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit fred.py file inside /your_installation_path/python2.7/site-packages/pandas_datareader and replace as below:

from pandas.core.common import is_list_like #COMMENT IT

from pandas.api.types import is_list_like #ADD

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 18.04, using Python 3.6 I resolved the error in the following way.

`cd /home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_datareader`

```
subl fred.py
```

and I changed the first line of code which was

```
from pandas.core.common import is_list_like
```

to

```
from pandas.api.types import is_list_like
```