# Problem importing pandas_datareader in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get historic and current data stock prices from yahoo finance and/or google finance with python. To do so, I installed pandas and pandas_datareader on my machine. When I import pandas everything goes fine, but when I import pandas_datareader I get an error. More specifically, the following script

```
import pandas
import pandas_datareader
```

generates the following error

```
  File "a.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pandas_datareader
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_datareader/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .data import (DataReader, Options, get_components_yahoo,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_datareader/data.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pandas_datareader.fred import FredReader
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_datareader/fred.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.core.common import is_list_like
ImportError: cannot import name 'is_list_like'
```

I tried to reinstall pandas_datareader, but It still doesn't work. Any idea what the problem might be? I use python3 on macBook Pro (beginning 2015) with macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.5.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [import pandas\_datareader gives ImportError: cannot import name 'is\_list\_like'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50394873/import-pandas-datareader-gives-importerror-cannot-import-name-is-list-like)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.core.common.is_list_like = pd.api.types.is_list_like
import pandas_datareader
```

and let me know if it worked :)