# pandas_datareader "cannot import name data"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to import pandas into my program to make a financial program, and my code looks like so (My IDE is PyCharm)-

```
from pandas_datareader import data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
```

However, when I try to run the code, I get this error message-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/benjamin/PycharmProjects/pandas/venv/pandas.py", line 1, in <module>
from pandas_datareader import data
File "/Users/benjamin/PycharmProjects/pandas/venv/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/pandas_datareader/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
from .data import (DataReader, Options, get_components_yahoo,
File "/Users/benjamin/PycharmProjects/pandas/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas_datareader/data.py", line 7, in <module>
from pandas_datareader.av.forex import AVForexReader
File "/Users/benjamin/PycharmProjects/pandas/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas_datareader/av/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from pandas_datareader.base import _BaseReader
File "/Users/benjamin/PycharmProjects/pandas/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py", line 7, in <module>
import pandas.compat as compat
File "/Users/benjamin/PycharmProjects/pandas/venv/pandas.py", line 1, in <module>
from pandas_datareader import data
ImportError: cannot import name data
```

Comment: Rename your file to something other than “pandas.py” (or any other package names).

Comment: What have you tried? A quick Google search for this error resulted in a few other questions which were solved by updating or reinstalling. Also as @abccd stated naming your file `pandas.py` is definitely playing with fire.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I changed the file's name, and the program is now resulting in an error message that says that Python is not installed as a framework for my computer. However, it is installed. (Sorry if I am a noob, as I am new to programming)

Comment: In fact, if I delete the matplotlib line, all error messages go away. Any idea what this is about?

Answer (score 2):

Your pandas version should be >= 0.19.0 to import data from **pandas_datareader**.

[Pandas Datareader](https://pypi.org/project/pandas-datareader/)

Answer (score 0):

Check this question for more clues:

[import pandas_datareader gives ImportError: cannot import name 'is_list_like'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50394873/import-pandas-datareader-gives-importerror-cannot-import-name-is-list-like)

use 'pip freeze' to get list of modules with version number and check for any inconsistency